# how to check the validity of a file by some conditions

Tags: bash

I run this command to execute remote SSH command on my Cisco switch:

```bash
ssh myswitch 'show ip arp' > myswitch.txt
```

The correct output should be something like this:

```
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  1.1.1.1.251          0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  1.1.1.1.252          0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  1.1.1.1.253          0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  1.1.1.1.254          0   Incomplete      ARPA
```

Or like this:

```
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  1.1.1.1.252          0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  1.1.1.1.253        170   fazh.3e1a.7pxz  ARPA   Vlan123
Internet  1.1.1.1.254         70   fazh.3e53.ya31  ARPA   Vlan123
```

I added the first line (Protocol, Address, ...) which is the header lines to know what each column means.

The last line of the output should either of these two lines:

```
Internet  1.1.1.1.254          0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  1.1.1.1.254         70   fazh.3q53.9l3g  ARPA   Vlan123
```

If the output's last line is like this (one of these lines only, not both ones), then the output is correct, otherwise it is incorrect.

If it's incorrect, then it should run the ssh command again until it's correct.

Some samples of incorrect output:

```
Internet  1.1.1.1
Internet  1.1.1.1.224         70
Internet  1.1.1.1.224         70   fazh.3e53
Internet  1.1.1.1.224          0   Incomp
Internet  1.1.1.1.224         70   fazh.3q53.9l3g  ARPA   Vlan123 #eventhough it's correct, but it's not the last ip
```

The last line's IP should be either 1.1.1.254 or 1.1.1.253.

How can I check the `myswitch.txt` if the conditions are met or not, and if not, then run the SSH again until it's the correct one?

I didn't do any attempt because I don't know yet what commands should be used.

Comment: Regarding "I didn't do any attempt because I don't know yet what commands should be used." - you're trying to manipulate text and the general purpose text manipulation tool available on all Unix boxes is `awk` so a command that could be used is `awk`. You've asked multiple `awk` and `python` questions in the past so you should should have a good idea how to use both by now so pick one and once you've attempted using that, [edit] your question to show your attempt so we can help you further.

Comment: I'd suggest `tail` and `grep` ...

Comment: @Grobu it'd be harder to do this robustly with grep than with awk since the test for IP address has to be on field 2 and grep doesn't know anything about fields so while with awk you can do the intuitive `awk '$2 ~ /^foo$/'` with grep you'd have to do `grep '^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+foo([[:space:]]+|$)'` and most people don't do that correctly, they just do `grep 'foo'` or similar, and so they end up with a fragile solution that'll break the first time the expected IP address shows up as part of some other field/string.

Comment: @EdMorton hello sir, yes I know I could have done this with `grep` and `awk`, but I had no idea how to do that because there were several hours I was busy with this issue, and I had fine output one time and another time I had output with issue as I asked. I was checking almost everything if **I** had done anything wrong in my commands. Thanks for the hint and comment.

Comment: @EdMorton I was thinking sooooo much why I have this output. I checked my bash script line by line and finally figured out I have random output as I asked in the question. I mean sometimes I have thee complete output while another time output is not completed. If I run commands again it may be completed or not, and that's totally random:(

Comment: I don't know but you may want to look into whether or not `show ip arp` starts anything in the background that you'd then want to somehow wait for finishing before closing the `ssh` session and potentially truncating the output, e.g. `ssh myswitch 'show ip arp; wait < <(jobs -p)' > myswitch.txt`. Or you could just add a sleep to improve your chances of getting all the output, e.g. `ssh myswitch 'show ip arp; sleep 3' > myswitch.txt`

Comment: @EdMorton I added `sleep 5` but the issue I have is (I think) totally random. I couldn't find a clue why I have this issue, so I thought it might be good to fool it by this question.

Comment: You should really spend more time figuring out why you have the problem rather than spending time trying to work around it. I doubt if it's truly random and any workaround might not be sufficient. [https://www.google.com/search?q=%22show+ip+arp%22+incomplete+output](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22show+ip+arp%22+incomplete+output) produces several results.

Answer (score 1):

That's what you are searching for. A simple .sh script that checks the given IPs in your .txt last line. It can be expanded but since right IPs are only 2 you do not need to check other keywords.

```
#!/bin/bash

TXT="myswitch.txt"

until [[ ${CHECK_LOOP} == "DONE" ]]
do
  if tail -1 $TXT | grep -q "1.1.1.1.253" || tail -1 $TXT | grep -q "1.1.1.1.254"; then
    echo "IP matched in $TXT"
    CHECK_LOOP="DONE"
  else
    echo "Wrong IP detected in myswitch.txt.. rebooting!"
    # Paste your ssh command line here to reboot your switch...
    sleep 2
    continue
  fi
done
CHECK_LOOP=""
echo "Connection check completed!"
```

Comment: `grep -q "1.1.1.1.253"` would succeed given the string `0121314152534` existed in the input. Replace `if tail -1 $TXT | grep -q "1.1.1.1.253" || tail -1 $TXT | grep -q "1.1.1.1.254"; then` with `if tail -1 "$TXT" | awk '$2 ~ /^1\.1\.1\.1\.25[34]$/{f=1} END{exit !f}'; then` for a more robust solution as it'll only match exactly the desired IP addresses and only in exactly the desired position on the line. Don't use all upper case variables see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)